# Map data from one dataframe to another with new and existing fields

Tags: r, dataframe

In R I need to create a new dataframe (DF3) and map some data from two existing dataframes (DF1 and DF2). Some mapped fields will be net-new, some mapped fields will be existing with same name and some fields will be existing under a different name. The basic framework is this:

```
D1 = data.frame(
  "FieldA" = c("apple","banana","grapes","pear","orange"),
  "FieldB" = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  "FieldC" = c(5,4,2,3,1),
  "FieldD" = c(9,8,7,6,5))

D2 = data.frame(
  "FieldA" = c("bread","cereal","milk","oatmeal","smoothie"),
  "FieldB" = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  "FieldC" = c(5,4,2,3,1),
  "FieldX" = c(9,8,7,6,5),
  "FieldY" = c(3,4,5,6,7))

D3 = D1[,c("FieldA","FieldB")]
```

Using the above I am able to map DF1 fields to DF3. But I can't figure out how to bring over DF2 rows whilst mapping the three DF2 fields I need:

- DF2 "FieldA" mapped to existing DF3 "FieldA"
- DF2 "FieldX" mapped as a new column in DF3
- DF2 "FieldY" to existing column DF3 "FieldB"

Results of DF3 should be 10 total rows of data with column fields "FieldA", "FieldB", "FieldX"

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Comment: Thanks. I included the code as is thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the result you are looking for, but this line of code copies the desired fields from `D1` and `D2` into a new `D3`. The values are copied into the new dataframe by concatenating (`c(...)`) the desired values from the original dataframes.

```
D3 = data.frame("FieldA"=c(as.character(D1$FieldA), as.character(D2$FieldA)), "FieldB"=c(D1$FieldB, D2$FieldY), "FieldX"=c(rep(NA, nrow(D1)), D2$FieldX))
```

Output:
`> D3
     FieldA FieldB FieldX
1     apple      1     NA
2    banana      2     NA
3    grapes      3     NA
4      pear      4     NA
5    orange      5     NA
6     bread      3      9
7    cereal      4      8
8      milk      5      7
9   oatmeal      6      6
10 smoothie      7      5`

`as.character` is used for `FieldA` because otherwise the values are treated as factors and `D3` then contains a number referencing the factor level. There are many different ways one could deal with this.

I assume `FieldX` here is what you meant in your question. Since `D1` doesn't have that field, it receives `NA` values in `D3`.

Comment: Yes you are interpreting the problem correctly. I tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work. Something is wrong with the last part of `"FieldX"=c(rep(, nrow(D1)), D2$FieldX)` . If I remove that the first parts of the line act correctly and produce the intended results. But with it in it throws an "Argument is missing"

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the `NA` value in the `rep` command. It should work now.

Comment: That did it. Yahtzee!